# Use setstate by using the loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two array of objects. I want to setState of an variable by looping through this two arrays.

I have a state ,

```
this.state = {  selectedValue: {} }
```

I have this two array of objects ,

```
this.props.untracked.content && `this.props.tracked.content`
```

What I did to setstate is ,

```
this.setState({
        selectedValue: {
          ...this.state.selectedValue,
          [`${resumeId}`]: type
        }
      }
```

In another place where I was not required to loop .
Now I need to loop through this two and then I need to setState,

for loop I did ,

```
for (const item of 

[...this.props.untracked.content,...this.props.tracked.content]) {
    this.setState({
     selectedValue: {
          ...this.state.selectedValue,
          [`${item.id}`]: item.value
        }
})    
}
```

So, Can any one help me with this ? Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: I am confused should I call the setState in the loop or not?

Comment: Well ask yourself why you call it in a loop in the first place? You overwrite the same state until you hit the last of the item in your loop.... so why bother calling `setState` each time? In this scenario, the UI won't render all those different states, it'll literally only ever render the last `setState` call.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to do all the processing without `setState` and use `setState` once at the end.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter, if you call `setState` multiple times in the same iteration, it should still only result in a single render.

Comment: Yes, but it's usually just easier and less messy.

Comment: I disagree, your way involves writing more code to manage the state locally and then set at the end. I'd just go straight to the root of the problem and just pluck out the last item in the array and set it rather than looping at all - the loop in the example doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setState(oldState => newState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) when new state depends on the current one:

```
this.setState(oldState => ({
     selectedValue: {
          ...oldState.selectedValue,
          [`${item.id}`]: item.value
     }
}));
```

Also it is better to prepare all updates beforehand:

```
const updates = {};
for (const item of 
    [...this.props.untracked.content,...this.props.tracked.content]
) {
    updates[item.id] = item.value;
}

this.setState(oldState => ({
     selectedValue: {
          ...oldState.selectedValue,
          ...updates,
     }
}));
```

Comment: And One thing If I want to set empty in the else condition  ? Should I set it to  {}

Comment: one thing while doing the for will I come to know if it is looping from the tracked or untracked ? I mean from two currently which one is going on ?

Comment: is there any way while updating I can check weather the key is already present or not . if it is then no need to add

Comment: is there any to know which loop it is going ?